# Incorrect format Exception while trying to call C++ dll from C#

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, language-interoperability

I'm Using C# WPF.
I have a C++ test dll as follow:
.h:

```
extern "C" __delspec(dllexport) void TestMethod();
```

.cpp file:

```
extern "C"
{
    __delspec(dllexport) void TestMethod()
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"Test", L"Test", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
}
```

C# Code:

```
[DllImport("DllTest.dll", EntryPoint = "TestMethod")]
public static extern void TestMethod();
```

And when i'm trying to call to TestMethod i got exception:

```
an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I have something like `[DllImport("DllTest.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`. Specifying the calling convention helps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be `32bit/ 64 bit` problem. Seems like your C++ dll and C# calling assembly are built for different platform targets. Try compiling both for the same platform (either x86 or x64) and then calling the function.

Comment: Thanks!!!.. i edit my post with another question, if i have more than 1 function, what i need to replace instead [DllImport("DllTest.dll", EntryPoint = "TestMethod")] ?

Comment: @Evyatar best post that as a separate question. We prefer a one-question-per-question format :)

Comment: @CompuChip, yeah.. i ask a new question :P